# Angular date range picker - how to disable the same day when already using the min property to set the minimum date to today

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

When using Angular Material mat-date-range-picker I don't want the user to be able to choose a date range of the same date. As in the date range should be at least one day.

2021/11/25 - 2021/11/26 Valid

2021/11/25 - 2021/11/25 Not valid

Edit: forgot to mention that I'm already using the *min* property to set the minimum date to today

Comment: Thanks. Would be cool if there was also a way to do it with the range picker

Answer (score 0):

Try to set minimum date using something like this:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" >
   <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker" [min]="minDate" 
   [max]="maxDate" >
   <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date"    >
   <input matEndDate placeholder="End date"   >
   </mat-date-range-input>
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Typescript:

```
export class DatepickerMinMaxExample {
  minDate: Date;
  maxDate: Date;

  constructor() {
    const currentYear = new Date();
    var day = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
    this.minDate = new Date(currentYear.getTime() + day);
    console.log(this.minDate.toDateString());
    //this.maxDate = new Date(currentYear + 1, 11, 31);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm already using the min property to set the minimum date to today

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's supported out of the box. But, one way to do it is with a custom validator.

**Component:**

```
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dateValidator: DateRangeValidator,
) {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
        StartDate: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        EndDate: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    },
    {
        validators: [this.dateValidator.datesMustBeValid()],
        updateOn: 'change'
    });
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>Start Date - End Date</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input
      [formGroup]="formGroup"
      [rangePicker]="dateRangePicker"
      [comparisonStart]="formGroup.StartDate"
      [comparisonEnd]="formGroup.EndDate">
      <input class="ng-trim-ignore" matStartDate placeholder="Start date" formControlName="StartDate">
      <input class="ng-trim-ignore" matEndDate placeholder="End date" formControlName="EndDate">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateRangePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #dateRangePicker></mat-date-range-picker>
    <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup?.get('StartDate').hasError('required')">This Field is Required</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup?.get('StartDate').hasError('invalidStartDate')">Start Date cannot be greater or equal than End Date</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup?.get('EndDate').hasError('invalidEndDate')">End Date cannot be smaller or equal than Start Date </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup?.get('EndDate').hasError('required')">This Field is Required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Validator:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DateRangeValidator {
  public datesMustBeValid(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
        const group = control as FormGroup;
        const sdCtrl = group.get('StartDate');
        const edCtrl = group.get('EndDate');

        if (!sdCtrl || !edCtrl || !sdCtrl.value || !edCtrl.value) {
            return null;
        }

        const sd = new Date(sdCtrl.value);
        const ed = new Date(edCtrl.value);

        //ed is greater than sd, no errors
        if (ed > sd) {
            sdCtrl.setErrors(null);
            edCtrl.setErrors(null);
            return null;
        }

        if((<any>sdCtrl)._pendingChange) {
            sdCtrl.setErrors({'invalidStartDate': true});
        }

        if((<any>edCtrl)._pendingChange) {
            edCtrl.setErrors({'invalidEndDate': true});
        }

        //here we could return a custom error instead
        //to signal that something is going on at the date range picker
        return null;
      }
  }
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There another approach using a custom validator over the group. If we have some like

```
  range = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl<Date | null>(null),
    end: new FormControl<Date | null>(null),
  },this.rangeValidator())

  rangeValidator()
  {
    return (control:AbstractControl)=>{
     const start=control.get('start')?.value || null
     const end=control.get('end')?.value || null
     return start && end && end.getTime()==start.getTime()?
                {equal:'Enddate sould be bigger than startDate'}:null
    }
  }
```

the "range" is invalid when the two dates are equals. The problem is how indicate that the "endDate" has error when the "range" has error. For this we can use [custom ErrorStateMatcher](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown)

We are going to create a customErrorStateMatcher that "launch" error if one control has error or if its parent has error

```
export class ErrorStateMatcherControlOrParent  implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    let error=!!(control && control.invalid && 
           (control.touched || isSubmitted));
    const parent=control?.parent;
    if (!error && parent)
      error=!!(parent.invalid && 
           (control.touched || isSubmitted))
    return error
  }
}
```

Now we can define in out component

```
matcher = new ErrorStateMatcherControlOrParent();
```

And change the .html like

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  ...
  <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date" >

    <-- see how indicate "errorStateMatcher"-->
    <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date" 
              [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  ...
  <!--the error is the error of the "range"-->
  <mat-error *ngIf="range.hasError('equal')">
       Enddate should be bigger than startDate
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fe1ptd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-forms-example.ts)